# form action not working using thymleaf and spring boot in eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a form to create Department , like this:

```
<form class="mx-1 mx-md-4" th:action="@{/Admin/listDepartment/Add}"  method="post" >
                                            
                                            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                                        <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" name="id" />
                                                        <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1c">ID:</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>  

                                                <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                                        <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" name="namedepartment" />
                                                        <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1c">Name:</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>              

                                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
                                                    <button type="button"
                                                        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
                                                </div>

                                            </form>
```

and this is my controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/Admin/listDepartment/Add")
    public String addDepartment(Model model, Departments department) {
        departmentService.save(department);
        return "redirect:/Admin/listDepartment/create";
    }
```

but when i click on save button, it not working, the site doesn't even reload.I hope someone can help me.
This is my first time i ask in stackoverflow so i hope u ignore the wrong details.
sory for my english

I think I made some stupid mistake